# Word object is undefined in Word2016

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I am writing an add-in for Word. I have Word 2016. `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)` is supposed to return `true` in this case, but it returns `false`. And the `Word` object is undefined. Any ideas? Thank you.

Microsoft Word 2016 MSO (16.0.6326.1022) 32 bit on Windows 7 Enterprise

Here are some snippets of my code:

In the `head` of my `html` I have this:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="local/js/common.js"></script>
```

common.js starts with

```
Office.initialize = function(reason) {
    console.log(Office.context.requirememts)
    if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)) {
        //never gets in here
    }
    else {
        console.log("This add-in requires Word 2016 or greater.");
    }
};
```

The `Office.context.requirememts` does not have `isSetSupported` function

**UPDATE**:
There is one thing that I didn't think was relevant, but apparently it is. My html page on load redirects to another html page and that what seems to cause the problem. The reason I have the redirection is because when xml file has

`<SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://localhost/wordaddin/index.html"/>`

instead of

`<SourceLocation DefaultValue="C:\WordAddIn\index.html"/>`

the content of the html file is cached and there is no way (none I found at least) to clear this cache. So whatever changes I do in index.html do not come through. So on load of index.html I do `window.location='main.html?'+datestamp` and that does the trick, but then I am getting into this weirdness.

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <script>
        function init() {
            var timestamp = new Date().valueOf();
            window.location = "main.html?" + timestamp;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the Word version+build number?
Can you confirm that this is Word 2016 for Windows?
Please post your code. Any references or sources that you've tried would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me (and I must say this is a horrible solution) is to add a query string parameter to the address of html file in my xml

`<SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://localhost/wordaddin/index.html?1"/>`

And then I need to change this parameter every time the index.html is changed and re-attach the add-in.

If there is a better solution please share.

Comment: Do you mean this had to do with a new version you released? For us this sometimes happens in production for 2% of the users, and we did not release a new version for months.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `Office.initialize` on the page?  The APIs you mention are only available once Office has had a chance to initialize...

All samples you see should include the

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    ...
};
```

line.

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: yes, I do have Office.initialize. I have added more description to my question

Comment: In that case, and if you have Word 2016 for Windows, that should work...  Are there any other details you can think of?

Comment: thank you for comments. I found some more details to share and updated my question

Comment: We now keep getting this error more and more as well, and it only happens for 2% of our users in production. We have no clue on how to reproduce, as none of the characteristics allow us to narrow it down.

Comment: @Rvanlaak, I would recommend you open it as an issue with as much info as you can on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues

Answer (score 0):

there are many pieces of information here that are missing, so i will try to clear all my assumptions.
One thing for sure is that you don't require to be changing the manifest (what its referred on this question as  "xml file") in order to enable your scenario.

also.

a. I see you are in win 7
b. That you are using our file-shared based catalog properly configured as a trusted location.
c. that you dropped the manifest (xml) on that location.
d. that the source location of the manifest points to the right html location.

if all the assumptions above are correct, you should not have any problems.
I dropped the html and the js files on the same folder.

this is the content of the Html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

   <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="common.js"></script>

<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<script>
    function init() {
        var timestamp = new Date().valueOf();
    //    window.location = "main.html?" + timestamp;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()"> 
      Hello World!
<div id='result'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

note that i commented the window.location stuff as this is no needed.
i added a div to show the result of the requirements verification as well.

this is the content of the  js file

```
Office.initialize = function(reason) {
console.log(Office.context.requirememts)
if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)) {
    //never gets in here
 document.getElementById("result").innerText= "Requirement supported.";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerText= "This add-in requires Word 2016 or greater.";
   }
  };
```

And finally here is the manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
 <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
 <Id>90400971-e367-4e1b-b9bf-fc2163635c37</Id>
 <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
 <ProviderName>Juanelo Balmori</ProviderName>
<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
<DisplayName DefaultValue="Code FLow Word.js" />
<Description DefaultValue="Code Flow Sample!"/>

<Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="Document" />
 </Capabilities>
<DefaultSettings>
<SourceLocation DefaultValue="\\*name of your share*\index.html" />
</DefaultSettings>
<Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Note that you need to create a share for a file-share based catalog trusted location.

If all of that is in place, i am getting the expected functionality. if i change the content of the HTML file this gets reflected when i F5 the taskpane..

note that you must probably getting a bar to enable running local html pages, just make sure to allow that in the taskpane and you should be fine!.

thanks!

Comment: thank you for your answer. For one I can't make shared drive to work. I keep getting an error on add-in load `"Cannot find ...://myshare/wordaddin/main.html?_host_Info=... Make sure the path or Internet address is correct."` And second I am making use of cookies in the add-in and my guess is once I point to a share, the cookies won't work, that's why I set up a virtual directory and use `http://localhost/wordaddin/main.html` instead of `\\myshare\wordaddin\main.html` in the manifest. Any suggestions?

Comment: the virtual directory must totally work. Verify that your address is correct  copy and paste either your share or the url  into the browser and if it opens your page, this should totally work.

Comment: it does work, but the changes made in main.html are not reflected in add-in unless I change the manifest's SourceLocation to point to `main.html?<something different>` and then close add-in (just refreshing won't do it) go to all add-ins, refresh the list and load my add-in. Which is all very annoying if you do a lot of changes in html

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache? What web server are you using?

Comment: I cleared IE cache. I don't know how and if there is a way to clear the cache of the Word's built-it browser. I am using the IIS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Using protocol https may help.

For the first time loading, http or https works fine. If you are called back from some other site, you have to use https.